# How to run scala unit test cases in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatest

I have created a scala-spark application in eclipse. I am able to run Spark code but when I am trying to run scala MainTest.scala by **right click-> Run As** Their is no option to run test cases.
**This is my project structure.**
[image]
**This is my Unit Test Case.**
[image]
**No option is shown here.**
[image]
**There is no test tab is shown.**
[image]
**Dependency for scalatest:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_sjs1_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-M4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can run scala test cases by directly right click on the test folder. It will run all test cases but cannot run a single file in my case.